# Excel: How to clear the contents of all sheets except one

Tags: excel

I am trying to clear the contents of all sheets in MS Excel 2010, except "Dashboard", after which everything needs to be hidden.
The 2nd line of code, containing ClearContents starts with problems.

I have tried changing the ClearContents to just Clear, but the "Run-time erro '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. It specifically highlights the ws.Clear

```
' Clearing Contents
For Each ws In Worksheets
   If ws.Name <> "Dashboard" Then ws.ClearContents
Next

' Hiding sheets
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If Not sh.Name = "Executive" Then sh.Visible = False
Next sh
```

Comment: What problems and what have you tired to do to fix them?

Comment: Hi Killercam - I have tried changing ClearContents to just clear. VBA stops running there. Dont have access to the server right now, so I cant tell you what exactly the message was.

Comment: @Killercam I have added the necessary info to the question. Couldn't find anything on this site or any other. The focus is on deleting and not clearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Worksheet object does not have a `.Clear` or a `.ClearContents` method. These are methods of the Range Object. Try something like this instead:

```
ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `ws.Cells.ClearContents`?